# How can I render an imported data for a Table component

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am working with antd `Table` component, so for instance I could have these constants defined in my file

```
const dataSource = [
{
    key: '1',
    name: 'Mike',
    age: 32,
    address: '10 Downing Street',
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'John',
    age: 42,
    address: '10 Downing Street',
  },
];

const columns = [
{
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name',
  },
  {
    title: 'Age',
    dataIndex: 'age',
    key: 'age',
  },
  {
    title: 'Address',
    dataIndex: 'address',
    key: 'address',
  },
];
```

Then the table rendered

```
<Table dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} />;
```

Now the problem is when I try to define these constants in a different file, export and import correctly, `Table` component does not render. Console reads `Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined` . How can I solve this?

These are the export and import statements.

```
{
    key: '1',
    name: 'Mike',
    age: 32,
    address: '10 Downing Street',
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'John',
    age: 42,
    address: '10 Downing Street',
  },
];

export const columns = [
{
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name',
  },
  {
    title: 'Age',
    dataIndex: 'age',
    key: 'age',
  },
  {
    title: 'Address',
    dataIndex: 'address',
    key: 'address',
  },
];
```

```
import { dataSource, columns } from '../constants';
```

Comment: Can you add export import statements?

Comment: Can you change to   {key: "value"}  (note quotes) ?
Where is `item` used ?

Comment: There is no item in the array, I used `key: value` to make it simpler to read. I have edited at @MotiKorets

Comment: The thing missing now is where you call an object named `item` ?

Comment: That is what I am saying there's no `item` anywhere, it is something about antd framework. Everything works fine until I try to import, I don't want one file having so many things and looking dirty. If you use antd, try it and see what I am talking about. @MotiKorets

Comment: I've tried it and it works https://codesandbox.io/embed/antd-reproduction-template-2ho2r

Comment: There either a problem in export statement or some configuration issue with the packager.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [`Table` API](https://ant.design/components/table/) how to proper initial a table, you need a `dataIndex` property in `columns` object.

In [`columns` object](https://ant.design/components/table/#Column), you specify how to serialize the `dataSource`, so corresponding `dataIndex` will take the value like `Mike` and the `key` property will take `'1'`.

> dataIndex - Display field of the data record, could be set like a.b.c

```js
const dataSource = [
  {
    key: '1',
    name: 'Mike',
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'John',
  },
];

const columns = [
  {
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name',
  }
];

<Table dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} />;
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not the problem, the problem is that when I define the `columns` and `dataSource` constants in **another file** and import into my module it does not work. Please try that on your end and see what it gives you.

Comment: Try making a sandbox